# BitBucket SSH connection issues

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin, firewall

I am behind a corporate firewall. When I try  to push code I get the following error...

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

When I connect outside the firewall everything works fine.

Windows is logging these errors...

```
The certificate received from the remote server has not validated correctly. The error code is 0x80092012. The SSL connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate.

The following fatal alert was generated: 43. The internal error state is 552.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use one of below commands:

```
git config http.sslVerify false
```

or

```
export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true
```